# set header not working for filename in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file, express, download

all uploded file name are encrypted , so when i want to download those file i am changing file name with there actual file name which are saved in data base, below code should work but not in my case,
how to change file name while downloading

below is my code for it

```
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="' + fileName + '"');
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpg' );
res.download(filepath);
```

any help will b appreciated , please suggest

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[res.download() not working in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176982/res-download-not-working-in-my-case?rq=1)

```
res.get('/download', function(req, res) {
  res.download(__dirname + 'jsonFile.json', 'jsonFile.json');
});
```